# Pythonic way of reading strings from binaries

Tags: python, struct, binary

In a not-so-pythonic task of binary config parser into struct I really want to avoid those C-ish ASCII and wide strings' length calculations. Any ideas please how could I make this two string handlers into small lambdas for my dict w/o awful read\seek? Config has to be binary, pity, but this is prereq

```
def handlerAscii(f, len=None, configParsed=None):
    asciiLen = 0
    while f.read(1) != b"\x00":
        asciiLen += 1
    f.seek(-asciiLen - 1, 1)
    return str(f.read(asciiLen), encoding="UTF8")


def handlerWide(f, len=None, configParsed=None):
    wideLen = 0
    while f.read(2) != b"\x00\x00":
        wideLen += 2
    f.seek(-wideLen - 2, 1)
    return str(f.read(wideLen), encoding="UTF16")


handlers = {
    "bytes": lambda f, len, configParsed=None: f.read(len),
    "number": lambda f, len, configParsed=None: int.from_bytes(f.read(len), "little"),
    "dynamic": lambda f, len, configParsed: f.read(
        int.from_bytes(configParsed[len], "little")
    ),
    "ascii": handlerAscii,
    "wide": handlerWide,
}
```

Not related to the Q, but I would also appreciate the comments regarding 'len' reuse for key name in 'dynamic' case. It means the dynamic field's len is already parsed into dict under another key

Update: after the first answer now the improved handler looks like this, but anyway too big for lambda imho and len counting is still here

```
    cached = b""
    while (aux := f.read(2)) != b"\x00\x00":
        cached += aux
    return str(cached, encoding="UTF16")
```

Update2: after the second answer there are no files now, arg is just bytes. But the strings handlers are still use len counting I really wish to avoid

```
def handlerAscii(raw, len=None, configParsed=None):
    cached = b""
    offset = 0
    while raw[offset] != b"\x00":
        cached += raw[offset]
        offset += 1
    return str(cached, encoding="UTF8")


def handlerWide(raw, len=None, configParsed=None):
    cached = b""
    offset = 0
    while (aux := raw[offset : offset + 2]) != b"\x00\x00":
        cached += aux
        offset += 2
    return str(cached, encoding="UTF16")


handlers = {
    "bytes": lambda raw, len, configParsed=None: raw[:len],
    "number": lambda raw, len, configParsed=None: int.from_bytes(raw[:len], "little"),
    "dynamic": lambda raw, len, configParsed: raw[
        : int.from_bytes(configParsed[len], "little")
    ],
    "ascii": handlerAscii,
    "wide": handlerWide,
}
```

Update3: I found takewhile() and succeeded with short lambda for ASCII strings. Just what I need! Now the last thing is to feed 2 bytes to it for wide strings. Thanks to all of you, now I like this code much more

```
handlers = {
    "bytes": lambda raw, len, configParsed=None: raw[:len],
    "number": lambda raw, len, configParsed=None: int.from_bytes(raw[:len], "little"),
    "dynamic": lambda raw, len, configParsed: raw[
        : int.from_bytes(configParsed[len], "little")
    ],
    "ascii": lambda raw, len=None, configParsed=None: str(
        bytes(takewhile(lambda a: a > 0, raw)), encoding="UTF8"
    ),
    "wide": handlerWide,
}
```

Last update, just in case someone would need it in future. This code is equivalent to the very first code snippet here, but to my opinion is much more laconic and expressive:

```
handlers = {
    "bytes": lambda raw, len, configParsed=None: raw[:len],
    "number": lambda raw, len, configParsed=None: int.from_bytes(raw[:len], "little"),
    "dynamic": lambda raw, len, configParsed: raw[
        : int.from_bytes(configParsed[len], "little")
    ],
    "ascii": lambda raw, len=None, configParsed=None: str(
        bytes(takewhile(lambda a: a > 0, raw)), encoding="UTF8"
    ),
    "wide": lambda raw, len=None, configParsed=None: str(
        bytes(takewhile(lambda a: a > 0, compress(raw, cycle([1, 0])))),
        encoding="UTF8",
    ),
}
```

Comment: The seeking can be avoided by storing the read bytes or double-bytes during the first reading at the while-loop.

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote handler like this (added to the post in update), but may be it's possible to avoid len counting at all

Answer (score 0):

You can accumulate bytes in a buffer as you go, thus avoiding seeks and repeated read:

```
def handlerAscii(f, len=None, configParsed=None):
    buf = b''
    while True:
        b = f.read(1)
        if b == 0:
            break
        buf += b
    return buf.decode("UTF8")
```

But normally you'd just read the whole thing at once and parse it in RAM entirely. How big are those files anyway?

Comment: Thanks, I already rewrote the handlers to smth like you propose after the first comment. Please check the post update. Also would change the arg now and use bytes in RAM w/o any read(), sure. I have them in caller anyway. Regarding the files - they are just malicious executables (I automate my config decryption task here), so I wouldn't expect larger than 500KB too often, would fit in RAM nicely. Anyway, the main part of Q remains - is there a way not to could the len at all